# extracting template types from struct

Tags: c++, templates

I have the simple tag struct

```
template<typename...>
struct tag{};
```

and a class

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class Impl {
  public:
    T func(Args...);
};
```

Is it possible to have a conversion/specialization or something, to allow to write `Impl<int, tag<int, double>>` and have it converted to `Impl<int, int, double>` a helper struct would work too.

I have tried using template template parameters but this seems to work the other way around, i.e. putting the types into a template. I also tried using a type alias inside `tag`:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct tag {
    using types = Args;
};
```

but this is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declarations declare different types, but if you don't need them to be the same type, you could add a specialization that inherits from `Impl<T, Args...>`:

```cpp
template <class T, class... Args>
class Impl<T, tag<Args...>> : public Impl<T, Args...> {
public:
    using type = Impl<T, Args...>;
    using Impl<T, Args...>::Impl;
    using Impl<T, Args...>::operator=;
};
```

`Impl<T, tag<Args...>>` will now have the member functions of `Impl<T, Args...>` available. Also `Impl<T, tag<Args...>>::type` will be available for declarations:

```cpp
int main() {
    Impl<int, tag<int, double>> a;
    Impl<int, tag<int, double>>::type b;
    
    a.func(2, 3.14159);
    b.func(2, 3.14159);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cG9zjK6Gv)

Answer (score 3):

Tool which can do this on any class template not only `Impl`:

```cpp
template<template<typename...> typename OnT, typename Tag, typename...Args>
struct apply_tag_on;

template<template<typename...> typename OnT,  template<typename...> typename Source, typename...TagArgs, typename...Args>
struct apply_tag_on<OnT, Source<TagArgs...>, Args...>
{
    using type = OnT<Args..., TagArgs...>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename OnT, typename Tag, typename...Args>
using apply_tag_on_t = typename apply_tag_on<OnT, Tag, Args...>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9q5P79Pv5

Comment: next step would be make it work not only for `tag` ;)

Comment: done since this is simple improvement.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...>
struct tag{};

template <template<typename, typename...> class T, typename R, typename A>
struct Apply;

template <template<typename, typename...> class T,  typename R, typename... Args>
struct Apply<T, R, tag<Args...>>: std::type_identity<T<R, Args...>> {};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class Impl {
  public:
    T func(Args...);
};

int main() {
    Apply<Impl, int, tag<int, float>>::type impl;
    impl.func(0, 1.0);
}
```

Here `Apply<Impl, int, tag<int, float>>::type` denotes the type `Impl<int, int, float>`.